# How to handle GridColums and Rows?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a code that adds new elements to a grid:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
            el.Height = 200;
            el.Width = 200;
            el.StrokeThickness = 5;
            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
            mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
            el.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
            ViewGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            ViewGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            Grid.SetColumn(el, i);
            ViewGrid.Children.Add(el);
        }
```

My problem is that I want to start a new Row as soon as my current Column is full. As the window can be resized, I never know how many Elements can fit into one Column, so I also can't just assign a new Row when adding them.

Is there any way to make the Grid (or any other type of "table") handle this?

Comment: Please check the WrapPanel: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/wrappanel It might just do what you want it to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your Grid into GridView

```
<GridView Name="ViewGrid"/>
```

Use the following code to put items in it.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
{
      Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
      el.Height = 200;
      el.Width = 200;
      el.StrokeThickness = 5;
      SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
      mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
      el.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
      ViewGrid.Items.Add(el);
}
```